# If not $b<a$, then $a\leq b$

Tags: inequality, order-theory, real-numbers

In trying to prove the following inequality $\neg(a\leq b)\Longrightarrow b<a$ i could produce the following indirect proof:

Let $\neg(a\leq b)$.

Let $\neg(b<a)$

But $\neg(b<a)\Longrightarrow a\leq b$. By using the trichotomy law.

But since we have assumed  $\neg(a\leq b)$. we have a contradiction

Hence $b<a$

However for a direct proof the following proof was suggested to me

"You start with axiom $(a < b)\ V\ (a = b)\ V\ (a > b).$ One of those three possibilities must be true.

$\neg(a \le b) \implies \neg\{(a < b)\ V\ (a = b)\}.$

$\therefore \neg(a \le b) \implies \{\neg(a < b) \wedge \neg(a = b)\}.$ Two are false.

$\therefore \neg(a \le b) \implies a > b.$ The one remaining is true"

Is this direct proof correct??

Comment: Have you hear of trichotomy?

Comment: i have used trichotomy in my idirect proof

Comment: Yes, these proofs are correct.